# One word for "someone working far away"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, expressions, synonyms, american-english

To say that since you're working in different location which is far away you won't be able to handle this activity.

Comment: Do you really mean "far away", such as on different continents?

Comment: @Spencer exactly

Comment: How about "overseas"?

Comment: In the general case this is "working remotely".  This can mean simply working from home, or it could mean working from the other side of the continent.

Comment: It’s typical in my workplace to simply say, “I won’t be able to < attend, drive, participate in > the meeting because I’ll be in Germany that week.  Or if the location is secret, “on travel” or “on a business trip”

Comment: @HotLicks My last employer, based on eastern England, had someone who had moved to Wales but continued to do her job from there. On the back of this another employee whose partner got a 12 month contract in the Falkland Islands managed to go with her but to keep on doing his job from Port Stanley. Both these people were said to be "working remotely".

Answer (score 1):

This is called [telecommuting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommuting).

> Telecommuting, also called telework, teleworking, working from home, mobile work, remote work, and flexible workplace,[1][2] is a work arrangement in which employees do not commute or travel (e.g. by bus or car) to a central place of work, such as an office building, warehouse, or store.
>   Wikipedia

Comment: Let me be bit more precise. The person is working from different country so he/she won't be able to drive the meeting.

Comment: Then say they will *have* to telecommute.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of saying "telecommuting" is to **work remote**, meaning to work from a remote location.  You can also say that Jane is a *remote employee*.  See [What’s Your Company’s Definition of Remote Work?](https://remote.co/whats-your-companys-definition-of-remote-work/)

Answer (score 0):

When working at a different location (different property) than usual, we would say "*off-site*":

"I won't be at the finance meeting on Monday because I'll be off-site." AmE

Answer (score 0):

You can say that you're [overseas](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overseas)

> In or to a foreign country, especially one across the sea.
>   *he spent quite a lot of time working overseas*